# Create a Dynamically Updating Blog

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I've used AJAX before, but only with sending, storing, and processing form data.

I'm working on a blog website with a high frequency of posts that needs to be updated in real time. For example, when a user on the admin page posts a blog, another user on the main user site needs to see that new post instantly. Or if someone directly adds a blog post into the DB, a similar thing needs to happen.

How could I get jQuery to persistently listen to the server and update whenever (a) a different user on a different page posts a new entry or (b) some admin posts data to the DB without ever even using the website.

Answer (score 1):

"Another user on the main user site needs to see that new post instantly": Not generally possible, within normal usage of the HTTP spec.

You can poll every 30 seconds or 60 seconds, to see if something's changed, however.. Make sure the 'polling' request & processing are very inexpensive, especially in the case nothing's changed.

(There are workarounds to the first statement.. I used one successfully once. But it relies on keeping the connection open & the server waiting, until an event happens or the polling period, 10s, times out.

On Tomcat this would tie threads up, but for our small number of required users it worked fine. Almost certainly not applicable to you, with an open public userbase, though.)